# Is Delphi Prism superior to RemObjects Oxygene in any significant respect?

Tags: oxygene

We have two separate tags:

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oxygene/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi-prism/info

They read like those are different products, more so like Prism is a superset of Oxygen and the latter is "just compiler" and Prism to Oxygene is like Lazarus to FPC.

Maybe that was the picture somewhen. But looking at [Prism withdrawal](http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/mh/2013/04/17/p5822), i wonder if there still are some things in Prism that are missed from Oxygene ?

If not, then there is probably a time to make [oxygene](/questions/tagged/oxygene) the One True Tag and make [delphi-prism](/questions/tagged/delphi-prism) just an alias to `Oxygene` ?

Comment: This question belongs on [meta], not here. SO is for programming questions; Meta is for discussions on how SO functions.

Comment: @KenWhite HOW to merge tags - is question for meta. WHETHER to merge or not - that is not question for meta. How do you think, who on Meta can compare to Oxygene IDE packages form tech point of view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the other way around. Prism was *just* the .NET "flavor" of the Oxygene compiler. Oxygene includes everything that Prism did, plus a whole lot more. [Oxygene](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene/) also includes the Java flavor (for Android development) as well as the soon to be released "Cocoa" edition which is currently code named "Nougat" (for Mac and iOS development).

When Delphi Prism was first released there was some existing .NET resources that were bundled with it, but they deprecated and removed shortly after. Most of the Delphi Prism and Prism releases were solely a subset of Oxygene.

The difference you read in the descriptions comes down to branding. Technically there is none.

In an unrelated note, if you find yourself doing both Oxygene for .NET and Delphi development then you should check out [Hydra](http://remobjects.com/hydra) too.

Answer (score 3):

We're in the process of getting the two tags merged, yes. fwiw, Prism is not and never has been a super-set to Oxygene. Prism is/was the exact same thing as Oxygene for .NET.

(that said, this discussion would really belong on meta?)

Comment: And this answer should have been a comment to the question. :-)

Comment: How discussion of comparing two IDEs could go on meta ? Discussion of merging tags belongs to meta, but this question was not about HOIW to merge tags but WHETHER tags had to be merged

Comment: @Ken: true ;). wondering if you could assist us with getting the two tags merged, since you do seem to have the necessary reputation, which neither of us here at RO does?

Comment: @marchoffman: I can try, but I don't have enough rep to make Prism a synonym of Oxygene (I have zero answer points in Oxygene); I have sufficient for doing the reverse (making Oxygene a synonym of Prism). I can propose it on [meta] the other direction if you'd like, though.

Comment: @KenWhite That is about how it might be requested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142166 Dunno if the tag might be renamed afterwards. Despite Prism wiki is slightly better overall making delphi-prism main tag makes little sense to me. I guess it would be better to edit dozen of answered d-p questions and add Oxygene tag to them. Then O-tag would hopefully get enough ground to be made a target of the merging.

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yes, I'm familiar with that. I asked Marc to clarify which way he wanted to do it. I have enough rep to directly suggest a change to add `oxygene` as a synonym for `delphi-prism` without a meta post, but not the other way. I know how SO works. :-) Thanks, though.

Comment: How many answers should Oxygene tag obtain to possibly become the target of merging ? @KenWhite

Comment: @Arioch'The; I don't know. I've been going back to the old Prism posts and adding Oyxgene tags. I'll make the best case I can when posting the request on meta. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite We've been doing it wrong. It is not big deal what are tags' stats. It matters what are users stats. Users that made answrs to tagged questions count. 
Some guy from top-list - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oxygene/topusers - should open http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oxygene/synonyms and suggest delphi-prism to merging. Then other guys should vote for it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177193/tag-synonym-request-delphi-prism-to-oxygene

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yes, as I said I'm quite familiar with how SO works. I've already requested the merge through a meta post (link in my last comment).

Comment: i just think that Jim or Marc could do it locally, without even bothering meta. But one way or another, no big deal

Comment: @Arioch'The: Yes, Jim could request that `oxygene` become a synonym of `delphi-prism`, but not that `delphi-prism` become a synonym of `oxygene`. (`delphi-prism` has more questions, and therefore is the larger topic.) It also can't be done by Marc (not enough rep either on SO or on Prism/Oxygene). Meta can get enough votes to have a moderator do it regardless of which tag has more questions and is therefore larger. As I said, I **am** familiar with how SO works. :-)